# How to handle antiquated questions

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Is there a method for how to deal with questions that are no longer valid?

In my case, I asked [a question](https://serverfault.com/questions/263592/401-1-errors-in-ie-not-in-firefox) which was never resolved, and I am no longer in a position where I could even test an answer if one were proposed. I'd like to help keep the site clean, but am not sure whether I should be looking to delete the question, or otherwise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to delete your own question - if not flag it (or let me know here) and I'll make it go away.  Anything related to IIS makes me feel dirty so I have no problem killing an unanswered question.

Comment: :) I believe I can delete it, I just wanted to make sure that was the best practice.

Answer (score 11):

If you run across other pepople's questions that are *horribly antiquated*, flag it and explain what's going on. We can put a Historical Lock on it; stops it from popping up on the front page without deleting content that we hope nobody will ever have to use again.

If it's just older software, and especially if it has a good answer, no need to bother it.

Comment: I like this approach better since other people may have a similar question at a later time.