# Should questions "solved by a reboot" be closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Based on the comment by the OP of [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/836765/205065), *"After a reboot, everything worked out"*, I flagged the question for closure. It's my understanding that [we close questions that are no longer answerable](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6777/205065). In my opinion "reboot your server" is a good suggestion, but not really an answer to the question.

Not feeling one of the canned flags addressed this situation, I used a mod intervention flag, which was declined with the explanation:

> How does this require mod intervention. Write a self-answer or delete.

I don't have enough rep to delete the question and, as explained above, my understanding is this question needs to be closed, not answered.

**Was I wrong to initiate an effort to close this question?**

*Based on the decline reason instructing me to "self-answer", I'm wondering if the mod thought I was the OP. This would explain the instruction to delete. If this was a misunderstanding, no harm done, but I'm still interested to know the Server Fault community's stance on handling questions of this type*.

Comment: I believe you're right that the question should be closed, so I've VTC'd it. As for the flag being declined, perhaps they did mistake you for the person asking the question; mods are only human after all...

Comment: @RobMoir Yes, only human, and I hope my question is understood to be focused on understanding the community's wishes rather than to point fingers at a mod.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm sure it will be

Comment: It make me think of me, I was flagging in the past a lot to be closed when I was under 3k. I got refused someday, and I understanded the mod opinion, as flagging should be for extreme case where normal tool like VTC cant deal with. As for your example, with a -2 score and soon to be closed, the Q will finish purged in the end.

Comment: @yagmoth555 My question is whether this post should be closed. If it should, then it should be acceptable to flag it for closure. However I can understand not using a mod intervention flag (in which case I'm not sure which of the canned flags would make sense. On Super User I would use a custom close reason.)

Comment: oh, yes. I agree for the close of such question! but there in SF usually flagging a mod mean an urgent closure or deletion, like spam, insult, etc. I dont know other site policy on the other hand. but under 3k that leave you not much choice except a DV and a comment to the OP

Comment: @yagmoth555 Got ya. Me neither, hence the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a difference between "I don't know what happened but a reboot fixed it" and "A reboot is needed because *reasons*". The later is useful, for those unaware that a reboot is necessary. Consider upgrading some drivers in Windows "Why my device doesn't work as I expected?", which is an expected issue if you didn't restart the system. Basically, it wasn't a **random reboot** that solved the issue, but a sensible process that is necessary to complete the task at hand. Those shouldn't be closed.

The ones that without any rhyme nor reason gets fixed by a reboot... aren't that useful, and might just get closed as "non reproducible".

Comment: This is Server Fault - _Have you turned it off and on again ?_ should be implicit.

Comment: I would disagree with rebooting for the sake of rebooting. If you are trying to find a root cause a reboot could erase the state you are trying to troubleshoot. If a reboot will make you happy why bother asking the question.

Comment: @RowanHawkins exactly my point. If the causes are unknown and the issue disappeared after a reboot without reason, keeping the question open makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Subsequent to my posting this Meta question, the [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/836765/server2008-r2-locked-out-partially) I referenced in my post has been put on hold. **I therefore conclude it was correct to initiate action to close this question.**

Based on the following comment on the question, it appears a custom-close reason was used:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a reboot solved the problem.

This is indeed what I would have done if I had the necessary rep.

It's still unclear to me if it was incorrect to use a mod flag in this case. As the question is now closed as "off-topic", perhaps I could have instead flagged it as such. However, I observe that *none of the close reasons available to me<sup>1</sup> reasonably describe why this question should have been closed.* Had I flagged it as, say "Blatantly off-topic," I would expect close-voters in the queue to observe that the content of the question is in-fact on-topic, and disagree with the close flag.

It would still be helpful as I continue contributing to Server Fault to know what is expected of me in a case such as this.

*<sup>1</sup>As of this writing I'm a 1.9k rep user and don't have access to the free-text close reason.*

Comment: On a side note check that meta post; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290507/what-is-the-guidance-for-using-standard-flags and check shadowwizard's answer, I think it's the best answer I seen on meta about that, but it seem a gray line

Answer (score 0):

After thinking to it, I wanted to give my idea about the question.

*For your main question: **Should questions “solved by a reboot” be closed***

**It's a case by case for me**. As like the example you gave, yes. The fact you talked of it there on meta accelerated the closure without any more intervention from you. On the other hand for a router or a switch, that a reboot resolve the issue, it can be a firmware problem or such that the trouble can come back later when the gear is in overuse, so it can be tricky to close all such question at first sigh. I v-t-c on the example you gave, but I would not v-t-c on all issue that a reboot might solve the issue.

*For the second part of your question, **how the moderator's reacted**;*

> How does this require mod intervention. Write a self-answer or delete.

I feel like RobMoir's told, as I just think the moderator though you were the OP.

I searched through meta stackexchange, and the usage of custom flag is not directly stated when to do or not, as comment like that seem constant;

> Well, as I see it custom moderator flags shouldn't be used to just
>   close a question, except in extreme cases e.g. bounty preventing
>   standard close votes, user who post tons of crappy questions, etc.

or there is a point of view that I like for using close flag (not custom close flag) wrote by womble;

> When you flag a question for mod attention, you are requesting
>   closure. As Michael Hampton described, it turned up in the close
>   review queue and, as I believed the question wasn't worthy of closure,
>   I clicked "Leave Open". A mod clicking "Leave Open" is not some sort
>   of super-vote that causes the question to be forever left open. All it
>   does is clear the flag (if I had skipped the review, another mod would
>   still have had to deal with it).

As you can see using a moderator flag can be tricky if the moderator don't think like you as from him a **leave open** vote will decline your flag, but keep in mind the intent is not to rebuke yourself. The intent is just that if the moderator don't think at 100% that it must be a direct closure, he will then wait the community to close the question.

Ofcourse, when you will be at 3K, this discussion will be history :)